# Get next datepicker and set the minimum date value

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a series of date pickers with a class assigned to each. What I'm trying to achieve is to detect (using) the date pickers onSelect() handler the next date picker and set the minimum date to the selected date plus one day.

I've tried using $(this).next('.publication_date); but this doesn't seem to return anything.

In fact, there could be a series of date pickers after the selected one so I'd need to set each of these individually.

Markup: -

```
$(".publication_date").livequery(function() {
 $(this).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd M yy",
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  altField: $(this).next(),
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log($(this).next('.publication_date'));
  }
});
});
```

Example Html: -

```
<div id="tierRight">
    <div id="tier1" class="tier">
         <p class="title">Tier 1</p>
            <label class="publication_date_label" for="publication_date_1">Publication Date: </label>
            <input type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" name="tier[1][publication_date]" id="publication_date_1" size="10" maxlength="10" class="publication_date hasDatepicker">
            <input type="hidden" class="publication_date_db" value="2010-11-24" name="tier[1][publication_date_db]" id="publication_date_db_1">
            <img class="date_clear" src="delete_grey.gif" onclick="$(this).siblings('input').val('');">
        </div>
    <div id="tier2" class="tier">
        <p class="title">Tier 2 <a class="removeTier" title="" href="#">Remove</a></p>
        <label class="publication_date_label" for="tier[2][publication_date]">Publication Date: </label>
        <input type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" name="tier[2][publication_date]" id="publication_date_2" size="10" maxlength="10" class="publication_date hasDatepicker">&nbsp;
        <input type="hidden" class="publication_date_db" name="tier[2][publication_date_db]" id="publication_date_db_2" value="">
        <img src="delete_grey.gif" );="" ).val(="" input="" onclick="$(this).siblings(" class="date_clear">
    </div>
    <div id="tier3" class="tier">
        <p class="title">Tier 3 <a class="removeTier" title="" href="#">Remove</a></p>
        <label class="publication_date_label" for="tier[3][publication_date]">Publication Date: </label>
        <input type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" name="tier[3][publication_date]" id="publication_date_3" size="10" maxlength="10" class="publication_date hasDatepicker">&nbsp;
        <input type="hidden" class="publication_date_db" name="tier[3][publication_date_db]" id="publication_date_db_3" value="">
        <img src="/delete_grey.gif" );="" ).val(="" input="" onclick="$(this).siblings(" class="date_clear">
    </div>
</div>
```

Trying to use the code below but the styles go all weird for some reason:

```
$('#start_date_datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd M yy",
                altField: '#start_date_datepicker_altfield',
                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                minDate: new Date(),
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    $('.publication_date').each(function(){
                        var current_tier = $(this).closest('.tier');
                        //Do all your stuff here
                        console.log(current_tier);
                        $(current_tier).datepicker({
                            minDate: new Date()
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: We'll need to see your markup to say how to get it relatively.

Comment: Nick, I've added some example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to go up to the parent `.tier` using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then, to the [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) sibling, then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the `.publication_date` control inside, like this:

```
$(".publication_date").livequery(function() {
 $(this).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd M yy",
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  altField: $(this).next(),
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    console.log($(this).closest(".tier").next().find('.publication_date'));
  }
 });
});
```

---

Check out your HTML though, there are numerous errors in there, random JavaScript fragments will give you issues.

Comment: Ah that's because I've copied it from Firebug.

Comment: @user275074 - That doesn't change the answer, the invalid HTML was just a comment in addition to it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.publication_date').each(function(){

      var current_tier = $(this).closest('.tier');

      //Do all your stuff here

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this should do...but it's not valid JavaScript, `.hasClass()` returns a boolean.

Comment: I can see this will get me all the datePickers but how do I individually set the minDate?

Comment: Question. Is the minDate going to vary for each datepicker?

Comment: Yes, the minDate will need to be 1 day ahead of eachother.

Comment: @user.. : Then access the previously matched element using .prev('.tier')   OR  Use a tracking variable for the date global to the each(function(){...})

Comment: Why can't I just loop over each .publication_date and set the variables this way? Why do I need to bother with current_tier?

Comment: @user275074: I was just assuming you're doin other things too.

Comment: No, I'd just be looking at changing the date picker, don't require any other items.